# ReactNative FlatList is there a way to track if user scrolled to the other end?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm building a chat app with React Native. To render messages i'm using `<FlatList`. I've noticed a performance issues if the message list is too long. My idea is to trim newer messages when user scrolls up, and load them again from backend, when user scrolls down. So far I managed to achieve this only with the older messages by using `onEndReached={loadOlder}`

```
<FlatList
 data={messagesRendered}
 ...
 onEndReached={loadOlder}
 onOtherEndReached={loadNewer}
```

is there is an option to track if user scrolls back to the beginning of the list and turn this pseudo-code `onOtherEndReached=..` into a real one?

Also any other suggestions on how to deal with the long lists are welcome

Comment: Have you considered using react-query to load with pages. (Pagination)?

Comment: @MarkEzberg I don't know what react-query is. Is it something that works with FlatList?

Comment: Read documentation about React-query. When your data comes from server, it doesn't fetch all at once but gives page by page on onEndReached and could significantly improve the performance. Yes, it works with react-native and flatlist. 
All you need to do is creating function in client side and cache it(react-query caches it if you provide the keyName). 
And you can call your middleware(so called client side react-query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a prop from Flatlist that supports this but it can be achieved by using the `onScroll` prop and checking the scroll value from the event.

```
const onScroll = (event) => {
  const { contentOffset } = event.nativeEvent;

  if (contentOffset.y === 0) {
    // User has scrolled to the very top
    loadNewer()
  }
};

return (
  <View>
    <FlatList
      onScroll={onScroll}
    />
  </View>
);
```

### Faster list performance

For your use case it might be worth checking out a recycler list such as [Shopify's FlashList](https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list) which can improve performance compared to React Native's FlatList.

Comment: Thank you! FlashList looks promising. Now I've got two options, will try to experiment with both

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called *Pull to Refresh*, and it's in the official React Native documentation. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)
Check out the `onRefresh` and `refreshing` props.

Check the **Example** [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol), where it uses those props but for ScrollView (they work the same, though).

So you can use test that code, change *ScrollView* with **FlatList** (props remain the same), and change the `setTimeout(...,2000)` with your code that fetchs newer items.

Note: Shopify FlashList mentioned by MK de Silva seems to accept the same mentioned props for Pull to Refresh ([here](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/usage))

Comment: definitely I'm going to use this for another screen with manual refresh. Thank you!